# ng-Change of first drop down not setting default selected value for second drop down in Angular with Kendo

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui

I am using Angular with Kendo.

I have 2 drop downs. One is for Device Type(Type1, Type2 and Type3) and second is for Power Level(range is from -10 to +10). When the page is loaded we set the Device Type = Type1 and Power Level -5 as default. Range for Power Level is same for all Device Types. But when ever we change the device type we rebind the Power level Drop down set to -5 and its related other controls.

We are passing the default Power Level value from server side for the first when the page is loaded.

The issue is when I am changing the Device Type DD ,  Power Level DD is not set to -5. It always selects the -10(first item) as default.

If I use $scope.$watch , I noticed that default value is changed from -5 to -10 as default which I have not change anywhere.

Here is my code snippet for PowerLevel drop down setting

```
   <select kendo-drop-down-list
   k-data-text-field="'Value1'"
   k-data-value-field="'PowerLevelID'"
   k-data-source="Model.PowerLevelList"
   ng-model="Model.SelectedPowerLevelID"
   id="powerLevel" ></select>
```

`Model.SelectedPowerLevelID` - has default Power Level value as -5. This value becomes -10(first item) when I change Device Type DD.

`Model.PowerLevelList` - List of Power level values.

The question is how to maintain the Model.SelectedPowerLevelID value whenever I change my Device Type. ?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution..

I have added the ng-options and k-on-change to power level drop down as shown below . OnPowerLevelChange() method helps to keep the selected value of power level.
OnDeviceTypeChange() method helps to keep the default value (-20).

```
 <select kendo-drop-down-list
        k-data-text-field="'Value1'"
        k-data-value-field="'PowerLevelID'"
        k-data-source="Model.PowerLevelList"
        ng-model="SelectedPowerLevelID"
        id="powerLevel"
        ng-options="c.Value1 for c in Model.PowerLevelList"
        ng-disabled="PageActionMode == PageActionMethods.READONLY"
        k-on-change="OnPowerLevelChange()"></select>

<script >

    // On change of Device Type 
    $scope.OnDeviceTypeChange = function () {
        if ($scope.$parent.viewModel.DeviceGenInfoModel.TypeID == 0) {
            $scope.Model = $scope.$parent.viewModel;
            //  Keep Default value(-20dbm) in scope temp value , So that we can set PowerLevelID default value(-20dbm) always until any change in power level
            $scope.SelectedPowerLevelID = $scope.$parent.viewModel.PowerLevelID;
        }
        else if ($scope.$parent.viewModel.DeviceGenInfoModel.TypeID == 1) {
            $scope.Model = $scope.$parent.viewModel;
            //  Keep Default value(-20dbm) in scope temp value , So that we can set PowerLevelID default value(-20dbm) always until any change in power level
            $scope.SelectedPowerLevelID = $scope.$parent.viewModel.PowerLevelID;
        }
    }
    // On change of Power Level 
    $scope.OnPowerLevelChange = function () {
        var powerLevelDropDown = $("#powerLevel").data("kendoDropDownList");
        // Since we use Angular with Kendo drop down , we need to set the selected/changed powerlevel using kendo drop down object.
        if ($scope.$parent.viewModel.DeviceGenInfoModel.TypeID == 0) {
            $scope.$parent.viewModel.PowerLevelID = powerLevelDropDown.value();
        }
        else if ($scope.$parent.viewModel.DeviceGenInfoModel.TypeID == 1) {
            $scope.$parent.viewModel.PowerLevelID = powerLevelDropDown.value();
        }
    };

</script>
```